# mysql server failed to start

Tags: fedora, mysql

I'm trying to connect to mysql server running on fedora virtual machine. Connection is established. But when I've restarted mysql server with this command :

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

stop is succeeded but start is failed!

I've tried with this command to start it but it's failed!

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

in the log file of mysql I had :

```
160509  13:09:58  [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'bind-address 0.0.0.0'

160509 13:10:03 [ERROR] aborting
```

I've done some researches, I found that the solution is to uninstall mysql server and reinstall it, but I don't want to lose the data in my database. How can I fix this?

Comment: it looks to me like the contents of your mysql configuration file would be helpful to see -- particularly the lines around the "bind-address" text. The file is probably /etc/my.cnf

Comment: based on [this link](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/66950/connect-to-mysql-from-external/) it appears that the syntax wants to see "bind-address = 0.0.0.0"  - where you are missing the equals-sign

Comment: I'm guessing there is no `=` between `bind-address` and `0.0.0.0`.  This directive can be removed so the server listens to all interfaces.

Comment: Where did you get mysql from? Upstream project or somewhere else? Do you need it?  Current Fedora ships with mariadb, which should be drop-in compatible.

Comment: Where did you find the upstart scripts? What version of Fedora are you using? Fedora is using systemd for years now.

Answer (score 1):

You can comment the bind-address in /etc/my.cnf:

```
#skip-networking
#bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1
```

also check that it is of the above format ,  `var =  value`

if you are connecting to the database remotely , check your interface ip by using `ip addr show` or `ifconfig` command , get the ip and bind it to mysql.

```
   bind-address                   = your_ip
```

for example if you server ( on which mysql is installed ) has ip 192.168.1.1 then it should be:

```
  bind-address                   = 192.168.1.1
```

for more details , see this [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: thanks for your response , it works locally ,
 but I'm connecting to database remotely when I uncommented this line `#bind-address   = 0.0.0.0`   I lost Connection  from the distant machine !

Comment: answer updated , you can bind your interface ip to mysql

Comment: I've made these changes  `bind-address= 192.168.1.5` , I saved  and I retarted : `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart `  stop is done but start is failed again ! 
when i comment `#bind-address` it's strated .. what maybe the problem here ?

Comment: check your logs and make sure the syntax is correct

Comment: No need for `bind-address` option even if you connect remotely.

Comment: As lev Bestritskiy said its not needed to ad bind-address in my.cnf, if you still want client to connec just give access to client db with below command GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO username.Clientip IDENTIFIED BY 'password';